# sigh... Accidentally hit "add files to project" on entire project folder & started a loop of repeatedly duplicating the project within itself

Tags: xcode, linker-errors

Wow... tail between legs...

So I clicked "add files to project" in Xcode.  My entire project folder came up selected by default, as it usually does.  I changed my mind and went to click "cancel", but accidentally clicked "add"... so it basically created this loop of continually adding my project folder inside my project folder... inside my project folder etc.. until it finally errored & stopped. (brought my project folder from about 25Mb to almost 3 gigs!!!

I went into my actual project folder (in finder, not in xcode) and deleted the duplicate folder that contained all the other duplicates.  But now when I try to build, I get all kinds of errors.  This may be the most embarrassing thing I've ever done.  I have a repo backup from 5 days ago, but I'd rather not lose 5 days worth of work.  Can someone please help me :( 1 billion internet points to whoever can help me so i can keep working tonight!

> here are the errors:
>
> Lipo Error:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/lipo:
>   can't open input file:
>   /Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-rtgmnzqeqhksvjbmtqtvnaudfgr/Build/Intermediates/appname.build/Debug-iphoneos/appname.build/Objects-normal/armv7/appname
>   (No such file or directory)
>
> Apple Mach-O Linker Error: ld: 5 duplicate symbols for architecture
>   armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation)
>
> Dsymutil Error: GenerateDSYMFile
>   /Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-gahmnzqeqhksvjbmtqtvnauibzrx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/appname.app.dSYM
>   /Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-gahmnzqeqhksvjbmtqtvnauibzrx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/appname.app/appname
>       cd /Users/Daniel/appDirectory
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil
>   /Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-gahmnzqeqhksvjbmtqtvnauibzrx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/appname.app/appname
>   -o /Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-gahmnzqeqhksvjbmtqtvnauibzrx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/appname.app.dSYM
>
> error: unable to open executable
>   '/Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-gahmnzqeqhksvjbmtqtvnauibzrx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/appname.app/appname'

Comment: Sounds like it should be more of an embarassment to the Xcode team.

Comment: yeah, it's ridiculous that this is even possible to do... but Im the one who clicked the button, lol so I can't point fingers.  I tried all forms of clean & even cleared all derived data.  any ideas?  I'm sure it is because I didn't remove the files properly and just deleted the folder.. but I don't know how to properly unlink all this stuff that it thinks it's missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: compile source][image]

I Don't know whether i will be able to make you understand or not but i have tried this weired thing just for you and I have got the same error. 
Then i found solution for myself, may be it will also help you.
Go to Build Phase -> compile source and then select all the files you see with postioning folder inside a folder like I have shown in screen shot below. you can see the main.m file inside slider/slider/slider..... where slider is my main project folder.
just check for it and press the minus button on the bottom . this will delete all the duplicate files from the finder. same for the images can be done like i have shown in the screen shot.
Then go to your project's finder and just delete the first folder which contain all the folders and project will run smoothly.
I have done this hope this will help you also. (please have a backup of your project before doing it ) :)

Comment: wow, thank you so much for intentionally recreating this problem just to help me.  Saved my butt.  I had to do a little extra fiddling here and there, but this pretty much did the trick!!  I tried this before, but it didn't seem to work, but since you said it worked for you, so I went back and combed every file real close in build phases, and there were some straggler duplicates hiding in the mix.  Thank you so much, again!!

Comment: any time buddy.....:) you can upvote it as a right answer if it helped you  .. ;)

Comment: Did I not accept it as the right answer correctly?  Sorry, I'm still figuring out everything on SO... I thought I already accepted it, it shows the green check next to it